# Publishing tutorials

Tags: publications, online-publication, statistics

What are my options for publishing tutorials?

I would like to publish tutorials for specific methods of statistical analysis using a third party software package with some of my own code for handling the data. Something along the lines of this example - [Analysis of Diallels using SAS](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBupLc4KXNAhUHN48KHf5-AdIQFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww4.ncsu.edu%2F~fisik%2FAnalysis%2520of%2520Diallel%2520Progeny%2520Test%2520with%2520SAS.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFgu4QRsyJEI1c0pU84D_Jbuu29UQ).

Comment: This third-party package is a commercial package?  They may have some help to offer with such a publication.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you are referring to may be suitable for [Protocol Exchange](http://www.nature.com/protocolexchange/). These protocols are not peer-reviewed, and you can include supplementary materials such as computer code. Or else, if you think your method would have wide applicability, you could consider submitting to [Nature Protocols](http://www.nature.com/nprot/index.html), which is peer-reviewed.